# How to switch the screen smoothly?

Tags: flutter

I have three screens: 1, 2, and 3.
I want to switch from screen 2 to screen 3, but when I pop screen 2 and push screen 3, then it shows screen 1 for a while, then it shows screen 3, so is there any way to switch screens using pop after push or not?

## this code not expectations

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute<Widget>(
    builder: (context) => widget,
  ),
);
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pushReplacement` insted of `push`

```dart
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute<Widget>(
    builder: (context) => widget,
  ),
);
```

Comment: i tried this way nma it's not as expected

Answer (score 0):

Using pushReplacement insted of push

Navigator.pushReplacement(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) => widget,
),
);

Comment: i tried this way nma it's not as expected

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not recommended to use both `Navigator.push()` and `Navigator.pop()` together in the same function call, as this can cause unexpected behavior. Instead, you can use `Navigator.replace()` to replace the current screen with a new one, or use `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()` to push a new screen and remove all the screens that come before it.